# Download api to use to convert text into QR image

Tags: android, qr-code

I am developing an app that sends love messages as QR image. Is there any API I can download and use to generate QR image in an offline mode (lovers disconnect from net and send this image via bluetooth)? I haven't been able to find any such API on the net. Does it even exist?

Also, why would I need an API after all. Can't we do it in the code? Has anyone done it successfully?

Also, is there a way to encrypt message send via QR code? Something like password-protected image.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). I was able to generate QR codes using this library.

If you want an example, see [Barcode Scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android) application that is based on ZXing, specifically [EncodeActivity](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/EncodeActivity.java) and [QRCodeEncoder](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java) classes.

Comment: I have used it as scanning library, but I wasn't aware of such feature. Did you mean it could generate a QR code (byte[][] array) or a QR image directly?

Comment: It can generate QR image that you can use in `setImageBitmap` for your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you with an input that may help you to generate the QR code: http://www.onbarcode.com/products/android_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html#howtojavaclass

Comment: Is this a finished app that I have to buy?